# Contraste de género em radicais atemáticos com ditongo nasal?

Tags: gramática, gênero, morfologia, fonemas, morfema

Frequentmente na morfologia definem-se, ou podem definir-se, 5 **classes temáticas** gerais. (É de referir que os autores como Villalva, Mattoso da Câmara, Bechara diferem ligeiramente nisto, e.g. na [Gramática Derivacional do Português](https://bibliografia.bnportugal.gov.pt/bnp/bnp.exe/registo?2000791) a 4ª e 5ª classe são ambas consideradas *atemáticas*.) Por exemplo:

1. o (gat**o**)
2. a (gat**a**)
3. e (dent**e**)
4. ∅ (azul+**∅**, mar+**∅**) - ou seja, nomes que no singular terminam em s, r, l, n.
5. atemático (avó, avô, lã, leão, táxi) - ou seja, nomes que terminam em vogal nasal ou oral acentuada; ou nomes que terminam em ditongo nasal ou oral acentuados; ou terminados em -i ou-u átonos.

Aqui podemos ver que os contrastes de gênero realizados por índice temático são triviais (e.g. gat(**o/a**))... Mas eu não consegui encontrar uma explicação morfológica para exemplos como:

- Orf**ão**-Orf**ã**
- Aqui derivados seriam Orfa-**n**-ato, ou Orfa-**n**-ar (com a dita ***consoante de ligação?***)

ou

- Alem**ão**-Alem**ã**
- Aqui derivadas seriam Alema-**nha** ou [Alem**â**-**n**-ico](https://dicionario.priberam.org/alem%C3%A2nico).

[Nesta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9397) excelente, o Jacinto já tinha dado uma explicação baseada na Gramática do Português da Gulbenkian para o caso de palavras terminadas em vogal nasal.

> Portanto as terminações -m do singular e -ns do plural são mera convenção ortográfica. Que aliás resultam da regra geral da nossa ortografia que dita que a **vogal nasal**, quando não é indicada por til (lã, leões), é indicada por m em fim de palavra e antes de b e p, e por n antes de qualquer outra consoante (incluindo s, quer este indique plural ou não): ele tem, vem; tu tens, vens.

A minha pergunta é dupla (necessário para que a pergunta seja completa):

1. Qual é o radical comum que nestes casos parece ter três e quatro *"alomorfes"* orf+(**a**/ **ã**/ **ão**) e alem+(**a**/ **â**/ **ã**/ **ão**)?
2. Como denominar estes contrastes de gênero? Parece que o **contraste é fonético e não morfológico**? Escrevi [neste post](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9464) sobre os contrastes de gênero lexicalizados/morfológicos, mas não me recordo de ter visto uma explicação clara sobre contrastes de gênero fonéticos.

Comment: Stafusa, já tinhas reparado nas 4 alomorfes de alem+...?

Comment: Não, não tinha, e ainda tenho que me informar sobre essas classes temáticas também - são novas para mim.

Comment: alem+(a/ â/ ã/ ão): alema?? alemâ?? alemã/ão=sim Por favor, explica isso.